# Changing color programmatically in a for loop does not refresh on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development. I am currently building an application that must flash different colors when a button is clicked. When the button is clicked I call a function. This function loops through a list of items and basically at the moment attempts to show blue and green after each other a couple of times. Problem is that it only shows the last color. And this only happens when the thread has exited the method. In the example below it is blue. I have noticed with some of the work I have done that screen changes reflects once the program have left the current method where the loop occurs and sometimes even longer after that. Below is the code :

```
   //Method that sets the color 

   public void SetVisualLayoutColor(int Color)
    {
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color);
        linearLayout.invalidate();
        linearLayout.refreshDrawableState();
    }

    //Method that loops and calls above method to set color
   public boolean ShowRepititive()
    {

        boolean successfull = false;

        try
        {
            boolean isGreen =  true;

            //for (TimingItem timingItem : items) {
            for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
                if (isGreen) {
                    SetVisualLayoutColor(Color.BLUE);
                    isGreen = false;
                } else
                {
                    SetVisualLayoutColor(Color.BLUE);
                    isGreen = true;
                }

            }

            successfull = true;

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Repeating Flash", "showFlashRepititive: ", e);
            successfull = false;
        }

        return successfull;
    }
```

Is there some way to get past this or to force the changes to occur timeously ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you explicitly run your code on a different thread, the code you write in an Activity, Fragment, or View will run on the UI thread.

When you are performing work on the UI thread, the UI cannot update. The UI only updates after your code has finished executing. Thus your for loop blocks any UI updates until it completes, showing the last color you set.

A more appropriate pattern to use would be to [use an animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html) to change the color

Here is an example of a very basic animation that does a cross-fade between two background colors:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofObject(view, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00)
    .start();
```

Obviously this won't achieve the flashing effect you are looking for, but you can define your own animations in a similar manner to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, your ObjectAnimator example above did not work for and I tried many different examples. Weird. But I then read further and came across the ValueAnimator and that worked fine for me. So my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As Tanis.7x said, you can't create the desired animation while your code is executed in the main thread. All potential solutions have to have a background Thread and a way for it to communicate with your UI thread. (see AsyncTasks,Threads,Handlers)

An alternative to ObjectAnimator that can work in your specific case is [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html). It's not that powerful but if it suits your needs, it's preferable since it's API 1 compatible:

You need to store a transitioncolors.xml in your drawables folder with your transition definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/green"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
</transition>
```

and then call:

```
 ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.transitionId);
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) v.getBackground();
     transition.startTransition(3000);
 });
```

where R.id.transitionId is:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/transitionId"
    android:background="@drawable/transitioncolors"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. This did work for me but I eventually went with the ValueAnimator.

Comment: Cool! Consider, when you have some time, to construct an answer and accept it, in order to help future readers with a similar question.

Comment: Thank you. I will do it maybe in the next week or so when work is back to normal. :-) It is a bit hectic at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research after I read Tanis.7x and Sevle's post, which put me in the right direction. For some reason the Object animator did not worked when I ran it and the Transition does not give me the flexibility I wanted. So I came across the ValueAnimator, which worked perfectly for me. I created my own class that extended the ValueAnimator and within the class I control how long each animation must be and also other aspects like running indefinitely until the user interrupts it on the screen. Thanks a lot guys, I really appreciate the help.